# nsinputstream to string?

Tags: iphone

Is there anyway to view the values in a nsinputstream such as converting it to a string?

Answer (score 5):

I'll assume you mean the data that's returned from NSInputStream:

```
- (NSInteger)read:(uint8_t *)buffer maxLength:(NSUInteger)len;
```

Try this:

```
NSInteger bytesRead = [myInputStream read:&byteBuffer maxLength:4096];
NSString *stringFromData = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:byteBuffer length:bytesRead encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are reading the data from a stream that is pointing at a file or a URL, you could NSString methods:

```
+ stringWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:
+ stringWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:
```

See the [NSString class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) for the documentation of these methods.